# The call "nets" in tennis, details

Tags: rules, tennis, international-sports

Question: If I used up my first serve, then am serving my second serve, and the ball hits the net and into the correct sector(meaning if the ball would hit that surface directly without hitting the net on the way, akka a valid serve) that is called "nets" ? The rule would have to be , me serving the first serve again, even though "I've already served the first serve" am I correct? What if nets happens again, be it on the first or second serve, do we have the same situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule you're looking for is: ITF Rule 23 – “The Let”

> In all cases when a let is called, except when a service let is called on a second service, the whole point shall be replayed.

The situation outlined in the question would be a 'service let' on the 2nd service as the ball touched the net before crossing it.  As a result you would remain on 2nd serve.

If something else had caused the let (for example a stray ball from another court) then the point would be replayed from 1st service.

Umpires often clarify the call by reiterating which service is being played.  For example "Let - 2nd Service" for the sake of clarity.

Comment: But, correct me if i'm wrong in the ATP tour, i think I've seen the first serve replayed after a second serve let?

Comment: The ITF rule looks pretty clear.  I can't see that an ATP umpire would make a mistake like that but they're only human - if they did a player at that level ought to pick up on it and say something.

Comment: @JimLowe: *"But, correct me if i'm wrong in the ATP tour, i think I've seen the first serve replayed after a second serve let?"* No, once the first serve is gone, it's gone.